# Derivative with respect to vectorization

Tags: matrices, derivatives, vector-analysis, matrix-calculus

I refer to the vectorization $\mathrm{vec}$ of a matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ as the vector in $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ with the columns of $A$ stacked one on top of each other.

I have a function $g(x,A) = (A^T\otimes CA)x$, for a fixed matrix $C\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, and with $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$. I want to compute the derivative of $g(x,A)$ with respect to $\mathrm{vec}(A)$. I expect this to be a matrix of size $n^2\times n^2$ of course.

If instead of one of the two $A$s I had a $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, I would know what to do since, for example for $h(x,A)=(A^T\otimes  CB)x$ I know
$$
g(x,A)=\mathrm{vec}(CB\mathrm{Mat}(x)A)=(I_n\otimes CB\mathrm{Mat}(x))\mathrm{vec}(A)
$$
and hence the derivative is simply given by $(I_n\otimes CB\mathrm{Mat}(x))$. A similar reasoning applies when I fix the first $A$. Here by $\mathrm{Mat}$ I intend the opposite of $\mathrm{vec}$, i.e. $\mathrm{vec}(\mathrm{Mat}(x))=x$.

To differentiate the whole of $g(x,A)$ I would be tempted to sum these two contributions obtained rewriting $g(x,A)$ in two different and convenient ways. I have however the worry this is not correct.

How can I think about solving this problem?

Comment: Your instincts are correct. The gradient of $g(x,A)$ wrt ${\rm vec}(A)$ is
$$\large{A^TX^T\otimes C \;+\; I\otimes CAX}$$
where $X={\rm Mat}(x)\;$

Comment: Thank you, so I can think to freeze one of the two parts and properly reshape the full vector based on what I need to differentiate.

Comment: It will be a matrix/vector version of the product rule for scalar differentials $(fg)' = f'g + fg'$. It seems Greg beat me to it. Perhaps you can reinterpret it like that.

Comment: Thank you @mathreadler , it was exactly for that reason that I went in this direction. However I was not able to formally motivate this reshaping/rewriting and hence I asked. Do you have a reference where this is well explained?

Comment: Let $\operatorname{vec}(X)=x$. The differential of $f:A\mapsto\left(A^T\otimes CA\right)x=\operatorname{vec}(CAXA)$ is 
$$
H\mapsto\operatorname{vec}\left(CHXA+CAXH\right)
=\left(A^TX^T\otimes C+I\otimes CAX\right)\operatorname{vec}(H).
$$
Hence its Jacobian matrix is $A^TX^T\otimes C+I\otimes CAX$.